# Can operands to `a?b:c` have different types? What's the best alternative?

Tags: c++, if-statement, initialization, c++20

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


struct Base
{
    Base(int)
    {
        std::cout << "int\n";
    }

    Base(std::string)
    {
        std::cout << "string\n";
    }
};


struct S : Base
{
    S(bool b)
    : Base{ b ? int{} : std::string{} }
    {}
};


int main()
{
    S(42);
    S("fortytwo");
}
```

There are are a couple of compilation errors with this code but the more interesting is

> operands to ?: have different types: int and std::string.

Constraints:

- `Base` ctor initializes constants so I can't use the ctor body.
- This is the only derived class doing the `bool` magic, so changing `Base` to accommodate it would be ... undesirable.

What now? The point of this code is for the derived class `S` call one of the overloaded ctors of `Base` based on a `bool`.

Considered solutions:

- An [IIFE](https://www.bfilipek.com/2016/11/iife-for-complex-initialization.html) could possibly work but be rather ugly and long.
- A helper function - same.
- Templating S and passing `b` there - I need a runtime decision.

---

EDIT: **@Yakk - Adam Nevraumont**'s answer is super awesome to the original question.

But I had missed a crucial detail. `Base` is abstract i.e. add `virtual void foo() = 0;` to it's definition. So it cannot be instantiated.

Comment: Your code makes no sense, your constructor accepts a `bool`, but you pass in an integer or a string literal then never actually save the values. I **think** you're looking for `any` or `variant` (or just multiple constructors), but I can't tell for sure because of the aforementioned lack of sense.

Comment: The ternary operator has to be able to convert its possibilities to a common type, which is impossible in the case of `b ? int{} : std::string{}`. But then aside from that, you have a problem where you're trying to make a compile-time decision using run-time information. The decision of which `Base` constructor needs to be invoked by `S(bool b)` has to be made at compile time, regardless of the specific value of `b`.

Comment: @NathanPierson that's an answer. I need to rethink what I am doing.

Answer (score 6):

```
S(bool b):
  Base{ b ? Base{int{}} : Base{std::string{}} }
{}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/Gj1a4ndh8).

You can get fancier:

```
S(bool b):
  Base{ [&]()->Base{
    if (b)
      return int{};
    else
      return std::string{};
  }() }
{}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/Yce7Ea1aP).

In the first example, a move is done; in the second, guaranteed elision means only one `Base` object is created.  You can test this by adding:

```
Base(Base&&)=delete;
```

Comment: Does this involve any copy ctors? A `std::string` ctor? Otherwise thanks a ton - I'll probably accept your answer after I go get some beer.

Comment: @Vorac 1st example is going to move, 2nd example does not.

Comment: The first and second are entirely equivalent as far as moving; the conditional operator can return a prvalue ([expr.cond]/6).  However, two issues confuse this: MSVC doesn't implement the conditional operator properly (in some versions), and the standard is wrong in claiming that "mandatory copy elision" can apply to base subobjects (which is unimplementable in many ABIs).

Answer (score 0):

As [stated in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68456547/can-operands-to-abc-have-different-types-whats-the-best-alternative#comment120984450_68456547), you can't do this with a constructor (with `Base` abstract!) because there's no way to wrap a conditional **around** the invocation of the base constructor.  You can, however, do something similar with a **factory** function:

```
struct S : Base {
  static S make(bool b) {return b ? S(0) : S("");}
private:
  S(int i) : Base(i) {}
  S(std::string s) : Base(std::move(s)) {}
};
```

If it happens that sometimes you know the `bool` at **compile** time, you might consider instead writing

```
struct S : Base {
  template<bool> struct tag {};
  S(tag<true>) : Base(i) {}
  S(tag<false>) : Base(std::move(s)) {}

  static S make(bool b) {return b ? S(tag<true>()) : S(tag<false>());}
};
bool f();
S i(S::tag<true>),s(S::tag<false>),unknown=S::make(f());
```